Using mysqldump on remote server in rsnapshot returns code 127 while the very same command used locally works fine
As said in the title, I want to backup my remote mysql database with rsnapshot, using mysqldump. I don't have any syntax error, but get a "WARNING 'command" returned 127", and the sql file is not written. Here is what I tried:
backup_exec    LeBear:"/usr/bin/mysqldump -A lebearcnc > /var/mysql-dumps/mysql.sql" 

and
backup_exec     LeBear:"/root/mysql-script.sh"

I also tried with --single-transaction and the database name instead of -A, but all different syntax attempts trigger the same warning/error.
"LeBear" being the host name in my /root/.ssh/config file, where the username is root. Connection is without password, as I have ssh keys. When I pass either of these commands on the remote host command line "LeBear", they works just fine, meaning the sql file is properly written. Mabe I should add that I don't have any ssh problem using the config file.
I would expect to get mysqldump to create the backup and write the sql file as it does when i send the same command locally.
Any idea how to solve this ? Thanks for your help.
Bernard

I finally found a solution. It seems that "backup_exec" does not take rsnapshot settings for ssh, like "backup" does. So the solution is to modify the line in
backup_exec     ssh LeBear "/root/mysql-script.sh"

without colon, as it seems to confuse rsnapshot which does not find a host with the name "LeBear". Logic, when you know.... ;-) No more error 127.
Maybe this can help someone else to not lose as much time on this as I did.
